# Is there a performance impact when using a method instead of a function?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, class

I like to work with classes and methods instead of bare functions. I am wondering if there is a specific performance impact to do so (either in execution speed, or memory usage or in other aspects).

A quick test shows that both perform equally well:

```
import timeit

class Hello:
    def hello(self):
        x = 9 * 8 + 3**5

def world():
    x = 9 * 8 + 3 ** 5

print(timeit.timeit(world, number=10000000))
h = Hello()
print(timeit.timeit(h.hello, number=10000000))
# 0.8460009839758439
# 0.8781686117747095
```

In other tests I did not see the RAM being used more in one case than in the other.

**Are there specific cases where performance will be degraded when using a class/method instead of a function?**

Note: I would like to focus exclusively on code performance, not aesthetical aspects

Comment: Try wrapping those in a lambda and testing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead of method invocation is really just the transformation of the `function` object to a `method` object when attribute access (`.`) on a function attribute it made from an instance.

Apart from that, the calling of the function is similar, with one extra argument (`self`) inserted implicitly for the method.

So, no, there aren't really any concerns to have here, the overhead is small and can be completely eliminated by assigning the method to a local variable:

```
meth = h.hello 
# use meth from now on
```

(Edit: In Python `3.7` [new op-codes](http://bugs.python.org/issue26110) where introduced that basically negate the benefit of assigning `h.hello` to a local name, the look-up for methods just got quite faster :-)

If you're looking for bottlenecks, you should be looking elsewhere. Python's dynamic interpretation really makes these sort of concerns pedantic.

---

As for the memory aspect, methods should be bit larger than the functions due to a method essentially containing a function as one of its members:

```
meth.__func__ # original function object
```

Despite this, I can't imagine a scenario where your application would choke due to the slight memory overhead methods introduce.

In CPython, for example, approximately 64 bytes are are added for a bound method object according to `getsizeof`:

```
>>> getsizeof(Foo().foo)
64
```

This isn't counting the `__func__` attribute, which contains the `function` objects:

```
>>> getsizeof(Foo().foo.__func__)
136
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method `obj.method(...)` involves attribute access (the `obj.method` part) which can be a non-trivial and therefore quite costly operation. A brief description of a possible attribute access scenario is found in the [documentation of the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors):

> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete
>   the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, `a.x` has a
>   lookup chain starting with `a.__dict__['x']`, then
>   `type(a).__dict__['x']`, and continuing through the base classes of
>   `type(a)` excluding metaclasses.
>
> However, if the looked-up value is an object defining one of the
>   descriptor methods, then Python may override the default behavior and
>   invoke the descriptor method instead. Where this occurs in the
>   precedence chain depends on which descriptor methods were defined and
>   how they were called.

Only after the attribute access is complete, invoking the resultant callable object is little different from calling a free function. Note, however, that in your benchmark the overhead of attribute access, i.e. the operations behind the seemingly innocuous expression `h.hello`, is not measured (though in your example it should be quite small).